# How can I make my code better? Web Scraping, XPath

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, tree, python-requests

Hope you are all doing well.

So straight to the point, my code tries to webscrape the results from a website, specifically the title of a restaurant, the rating and the address.

The code for the restaurant and the address works perfectly, but the code for the rating brings not only ratings but other values.

Restaurant bit: `//a[@class="arrivalName"]/text()`

Address bit: `//span[@class="address"]/text()`

Rating bit: `//a[@rel="nofollow"]/text()`

For the scraping I combine them all into:

`'//a[@class="arrivalName"]/text()|//span[@class="address"]/text()|//a[@rel="nofollow"]/text()'`

The problem with the rating isn't actually that bad because when I export it I can just delete the additional lines which are not actually ratings.

My problem comes with the way the results are displayed in the list. Which comes like, for example:

> 169: Farbatto Helados
>
> 170: 999 opiniones
>
> 171: \nYerbal 2413\n

I would like to have this but with a column for the restaurant name (169), another for the rating (170) and a third column for the direction (171).

> Farbatto Helados |
>   999 opiniones |
>   \nYerbal 2413\n

My code is the following, any help would be much appreciated!

Part 1

`import pandas as pd
 import requests
 from lxml import html`

Part 2

```
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}

url = 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires?a=+colpayo+132&lng=-58.44132490000004&lat=-34.6184536&doorNumber=132&page=8'
```

Part 3

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
```

Part 4

```
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

title = tree.xpath('//a[@class="arrivalName"]/text()|//span[@class="address"]/text()|//a[@rel="nofollow"]/text()')

df = pd.DataFrame(title)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have quickly written code to help you out, modify according to your needs..

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from lxml import html

header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.75 Safari/537.36","X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}
url = 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires?a=+colpayo+132&lng=-58.44132490000004&lat=-34.6184536&doorNumber=132&page=8'
r = requests.get(url, headers=header)
tree = html.fromstring(r.content)

hotel_elements = tree.xpath('//section[@class="restaurantData"]')
hotels = []
for hotel in hotel_elements:
    hotel_name = hotel.xpath('.//a[@class="arrivalName"]')
    hotel_address = hotel.xpath('.//span[@class="address"]')
    hotel_reviews = hotel.xpath('.//a[@rel="nofollow"]')
    if hotel_name:
        hotel_name = hotel_name[0].text_content()
    if hotel_address:
        hotel_address = hotel_address[0].text_content()
    if hotel_reviews:
        hotel_reviews = hotel_reviews[0].text_content()
    hotels.append([hotel_name, hotel_address, hotel_reviews])


df = pd.DataFrame(hotels)
```

## Output

```
                              0                                       1              2
0                 Double Crêpes           \nBernardo de Irigoyen 1588\n  144 opiniones
1            Empanadas del Chef                         \nRosario 749\n  230 opiniones
2     El Emporio Helado Natural                         \nMurillo 749\n   33 opiniones
3                    Vian-ditas                                      []             []
4                 Rios Peruanos                          \nYerbal 787\n   33 opiniones
5                   Puro Goyena                \nAv. Pedro Goyena 293\n             []
6   Rotisería Welcome Caballito  \nAvenida Dr. Honorio Pueyrredón 784\n  137 opiniones
7             Moreira Caballito               \nJosé María Moreno 735\n   62 opiniones
8               Game of Burgers                         \nSaraza 1110\n   82 opiniones
9                Salimos Fuerte                    \nRamos Mejía 1088\n             []
10        Fullescabio Caballito                    \nCucha Cucha 1420\n   59 opiniones
11                     Donovans                          \nPerón 1596\n             []
12         Don Ricardo Restobar              \nJuan B. Ambrosetti 704\n   37 opiniones
13                Titan Burgers                       \nAranguren 334\n   40 opiniones
14         El Rey de las Arepas       \nDr. Juan Felipe Aranguren 336\n             []
```